# Can every element of Hilbert space be represented by a linear combination?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $f$ be an element of $H$. Let $T:H \rightarrow H$ be a bounded linear operator. Then, can $Tf$ be represented by
$$ Tf = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k\langle f,g_k\rangle$$
where $f_k,g_k \in H?$

If the dimension of the image of $T$ is finite, it would be. But if not?

Comment: If $H$ is not seprable you cannot do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H$ is separable you may always find a countable orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_n$, so each $f$ in $H$ may be expressed as
$$
f = \sum_n \langle f, e_n \rangle e_n
$$
whence
$$
T(f) = \sum_n \langle f, e_n \rangle T( e_n).
$$

Comment: If $T$ maps $H$ to same $H$, then $T(e_n)$ is may another orthonormal(or orthogonal) basis different to $e_n$, right ?

Comment: No, the $T(e_n)$ would only form an orthonormal basis if $T$ is unitary.